# ASP.net GridView: hide Edit|Delete links

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have GridView with *AutoGenerateDeleteButton=true* && *AutoGenerateEditButton=true*.
I want to allow only registered users to use these functions therefore I want to hide it from unregistered users. How can I hide it?

I tried hidding the whole column but on page_load gridView is not ready yet so I get null exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your pageLoad event store user Role inside Session

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["usrRole"] = "1";
}
```

On Row databound event of your gridview check for the session & if not equal to your administrator role, set visibility of your delete button column to false

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (Session["usrRole"] != "1")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;   //0 is autogenerate edit column index
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;  // 1  is autogenerate delete column index
        }
    }
}
```