# How to hide the auto generated delete button in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to hide the auto generated delete button in GridView. unable to make only delete button invisible. while making invisible of delete button cancel button also not getting invisiable.

> cancel button is also getting invisible

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCompanies" runat="server" CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"
            AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvCompanies_PageIndexChanging"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No records found" OnRowEditing="gvCompanies_RowEditing" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowUpdating="gvCompanies_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCompanies_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvCompanies_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" OnRowDataBound="gvCompanies_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No.">
              <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("id")%>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" ItemStyle-ForeColor="black">
<ItemTemplate>
     <a href='services.aspx?CompanyId=<%#Eval("id")%>'>
<asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Company")%>'/>
         </a>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Company")%>'/>
</EditItemTemplate>
             </Columns>
              <EmptyDataTemplate>
              <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr style="color: White; background-color: #3AC0F2;">
                <th scope="col" style="width: 150px;">
                    SL No
                </th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 150px;">
                    Company
                </th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 100px;">
                    Company Code
                </th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 100px;">
                    Address
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="99" align = "center">
                    No records found for the search criteria.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>



 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    // Hide the edit button when some condition is true
                    // for example, the row contains a certain property
                     if (Loggedinuser != "kernel")
                {


                   e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2].Visible = false;


                }


                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.net GridView: hide Edit|Delete links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655357/asp-net-gridview-hide-editdelete-links)

Comment: can you post your entire gridview aspx code?

Comment: did n't understand your condition, why it is if(Loggedinuser == "kernel"){if(Loggedinuser != "kernel") // your code} ? , if your first condition will true it will never enter into second condition.

Comment: sorry pasting mistake hela.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to hide or show a specific column in GridView

Option 1:  Using the Cells index

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                if("your Condition")
                  {

                    e.Row.Cells[0].Control[0].Visible = false;//or true
                    }
                 }        
         }
```

Option 2: Looping through GridView Row Controls collections

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {


            foreach (TableRow row in GridView1.Controls[0].Controls)
            {
             if("your Condition")
                      {
                      row.Cells[0].Control[0].Visible = false;
                      }
            }        
    }
```

Comment: if i do like this cancel button also will be invisibe. while clicking edit button

Comment: hi please refer my answer again..i think now it may help you

Comment: hai in first index i have edit button and second index delete button.if im making invisible second index [1] then cancel button also will be invisible